# Is it a good practice to include an expected result in a testcase?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, nunit

Consider the following test:

```
    [TestCase(2016, true)]
    [TestCase(2017, false)]
    [TestCase(2018, false)]
    [TestCase(2019, false)]
    [TestCase(2020, true)]
    public void When_IsLeapYear_ReturnTrueForLeapYear(int year, bool expectedResult)
    {
        //Act
        var result = _sut.IsLeapYear(year);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(result, expectedResult);
    }
```

Is it a bad practice to include both the year and the expected results in testcases like that, instead of creating two different tests (e.g. one for expecting true, one for expecting false?)

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

No, in fact I think it would be a bad practice to make two tests that test exactly the same condition but one "expecting true" and one "expecting false", where one expects to succeed and the other to fail...

You only need one of those two tests. The second one adds no additional bug-catching value, only maintenance burden.